# How to change a variable IF a string contains X

Tags: php

I have an if/else statement where I am trying to change a variable within a string IF an input box contains an '@' symbol. This data ends up in SQL. Every time I look in my SQL table, only the string containing the 'else' statement is inserted.

The variable within the string should change If an input field is submitted with an '@' symbol, otherwise, if an input field DOES NOT contain an '@' symbol, the 'else' instance should get applied.

My code:

```
if (strpos($link, '@') !== false) {
    $webvar = 'This';
    $link       = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, '<a href='."'".'http://'.$_POST['Link']."' ".'target='."'".'_blank'."'".'>'.$webvar.'</a>');
}
else {
    $webvar = 'That';
    $link       = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, '<a href='."'".'http://'.$_POST['Link']."' ".'target='."'".'_blank'."'".'>'.$webvar.'</a>');
}
```

Even when I use this as my code: The string is output without the variable.

```
$link       = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, '<a href='."'".'http://'.$_POST['Link']."' ".'target='."'".'_blank'."'".'>'.$webvar.'</a>');

if (strpos($link, '@') !== false) {
    global $webvar;
    $webvar = 'Twitter';
}
else {
    global $webvar;
    $webvar = 'Website';
}
```

Comment: What is the $link you are posting into if statement? Your code seems to work fine: https://3v4l.org/N7RdL

Comment: The $link is only declared in the IF statements

Comment: I had this line: $title   = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['Link']); but I deleted it as it would insert whatever was typed into my input field into sql, and I need the added html to go along with whatever is typed into the input field.

Comment: So if you do not have $link variable assigned before if statement, how are you going to check for @ inside that variable?

Comment: Do you mean if(strpos($_POST['Link'], '@') !== false) ?

Comment: for some reason that's not working, neither is my update above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110743/discussion-between-siim-kallari-and-marlon-fowler).

Answer (score 0):

This works, with credit to Siim Kallari

```
if(strpos($_POST['Link'], '@') !== false)  {
    global $webvar;
    $webvar = 'Twitter';
    $link       = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, '<a href='."'".'http://'.$_POST['Link']."' ".'target='."'".'_blank'."'".'>'.$webvar.'</a>');
}
else {
    global $webvar;
    $webvar = 'Website';
    $link       = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, '<a href='."'".'http://'.$_POST['Link']."' ".'target='."'".'_blank'."'".'>'.$webvar.'</a>');
}
```